# Python Time Series Dates as Columns to Rows

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have the following dataframe in pandas:

```
3/2/20  3/3/20  Measure State   City
5       6       Deaths  WA  King County
0       0       Deaths  CA  Orange
14      21      Confirmed   WA  King County
1       1       Confirmed   CA  Orange
```

There are several additional date columns range :

```
1/22/20 1/23/20 1/24/20 1/25/20 1/26/20 1/27/20 1/28/20 1/29/20 1/30/20 1/31/20 2/1/20  2/2/20  2/3/20  2/4/20  2/5/20  2/6/20  2/7/20  2/8/20  2/9/20  2/10/20 2/11/20 2/12/20 2/13/20 2/14/20 2/15/20 2/16/20 2/17/20 2/18/20 2/19/20 2/20/20 2/21/20 2/22/20 2/23/20 2/24/20 2/25/20 2/26/20 2/27/20 2/28/20 2/29/20 3/1/20  3/2/20  3/3/20
```

How do I pivot/reshape so I end up with something like the below, but including all the date columns?

```
State   City     Measure   Date    Value
WA      King     Deaths    3/2/20   5
WA      King     Deaths    3/3/20   6
WA      King     Deaths    3/2/20   14
WA      King     Deaths    3/3/20   21
CA      Orange   Deaths    3/2/20   0
CA      Orange   Deaths    3/3/20   0
CA      Orange   Confirmed    3/2/20   1
CA      Orange   Confirmed    3/3/20   1
```

Comment: `df.melt(id_vars = ['Measure', 'State', 'City'], var_name = 'Date')` You want to melt your dataframe.

Comment: How does the data end up like that in the first place?

Comment: Because that's how the CDC publishes it for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Per comment above, melt solved my problem:

```
df.melt(id_vars = ['Measure', 'State', 'City'],  var_name = 'Date' , value_vars=['1/22/20', '1/23/20',
   '1/24/20', '1/25/20', '1/26/20', '1/27/20', '1/28/20', '1/29/20',
   '1/30/20', '1/31/20', '2/1/20', '2/2/20', '2/3/20', '2/4/20', '2/5/20',
   '2/6/20', '2/7/20', '2/8/20', '2/9/20', '2/10/20', '2/11/20', '2/12/20',
   '2/13/20', '2/14/20', '2/15/20', '2/16/20', '2/17/20', '2/18/20',
   '2/19/20', '2/20/20', '2/21/20', '2/22/20', '2/23/20', '2/24/20',
   '2/25/20', '2/26/20', '2/27/20', '2/28/20', '2/29/20', '3/1/20',
   '3/2/20', '3/3/20'])
```